# Error loading javascript code in content editor webpart in other browser except IE 11

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, jquery, spservices

I have added content editor webpart in NewForm.aspx in SP2013 and reading the code to javascript file called **HideFields.js**. The script is working as expected in IE 11 but not in Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

I got this error message in Firefox:
[image]

So the script as below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

     $().SPServices({
      operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
      userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
      async: false,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
      var xml = xData.responseXML.xml;

       //If the current User does belong to the group "Test Group"
        if (xml.search('Test Group') == -1)
         {
             $('td.ms-formlabel:contains("Description")').parent().hide();

           }  
        }

     });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: `.ps1` extension is for powershell files and javascript files.

Comment: sorry was typo. i have fixed it. Thanks